Citus: How to delete the database on the postgres cluster?
I would like to know how to drop the database on citus cluster. In my Postgres cluster, I have 1 controller and 2 worker nodes.   Is there any suggested way of dropping the database in citus cluster?
I tried to drop the database from the worker first and then the controller. But while I am trying to drop the database on the worker, I get the error below error
ERROR:  database "" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 2 other sessions using the database.
I even tried terminating the connection using the below command and then tried dropping the database. But it is still giving the same error.  Looks like the session is immediately getting established even after termination using the below command.
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '<database_name>'AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
Note that no other application or users are connected with the database which i am trying to drop.

I assume that you have Citus extension installed on the database you want to drop. If this is the case, you can run the following command to drop Citus extension:
DROP EXTENSION citus CASCADE

This will stop the Citus Maintenance Daemon process that can be responsible for the connection that keeps showing up. This Daemon is set up in a way that it will establish a connection automatically after the current one is dropped for some reason.
